# no match for ‘operator[]’ (operand types are ‘QJsonDocument’

Tags: c++, qt

I built a quick server using QT Creator on Windows, everything worked perfectly, I tried running **The same code** on my other Machine(Ubuntu) and I get errors, specially, in this line:

```
QString max_colorbar = doc["colorbar"].toString();
```

The error I am getting is:

```
no match for ‘operator[]’ (operand types are ‘QJsonDocument’ and ‘const char [9]’)
```

The thing that confuses me is why do I need to change anything if the same code worked on Windows(It's cross platforms), I thought it may be because of QT versions but I checked my version on linux and it is:

```
QMake version 3.1
Using Qt version 5.9.5
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: All of the `QJsonDocument::operator[ ... ]` say _"... introduced in __Qt 5.10__...."_ or later https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsondocument.html#operator-5b-5d

Comment: I wrote that I am using Qt version 5.9.5, I think @pm100 is right, I'll test it now.

Comment: You said 5.9.5 is your linux version, what's your Windows version of QT ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because [const QJsonValue QJsonDocument::operator[](const QString &key) const](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsondocument.html#operator-5b-5d) function was introduced in `Qt5.10` and you ran in on `Qt5.9.5`.

You could change your code from

```
QString max_colorbar = doc["colorbar"].toString();
```

to as follows which builds on Qt5.9.5 too

```
QString max_colorbar = doc.object().value("colorbar").toString();
```

Comment: Thanks, I changed the code to what you suggested, however I am getting an error: ```invalid use of incomplete type ‘class QJsonObject’```

Comment: #include <QJsonObject>